# How to install along side vista

Tags: hp, windows-vista

On a hp pavilion entertainment pc running windows vista have been unable to get it to boot from a usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you correctly wrote an image to an usb drive and usb drive can be read on another PC. Then reboot your PC and either go to BIOS and set boot sequence so it loads from your USB HDD or USB FLASH, or press a button to open boot menu and choose to boot from your usb drive. This should be enough, and if not - describe where exactly are you having problems.

Comment: I have already done this all it does is start to boot into the Linux and stops after writing one line to the cmdline

Comment: Have you tried another iso images? It may be broken somehow.
Also that first line may be useful, if you can provide it.

Comment: Yes I have tried other Iso and all it says is hp pavilion